# Unity Won't Open File

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpUYH.png)When I try to open a .sln file in Unity Personal Version 2017.3.0f3, it is greyed out. The .sln file I'm trying to open is downloaded from a class I'm taking on Coursera, and I've never had a problem before. However, when I try to open other .sln files that I've successfully opened in the past, they're now also greyed out. The only way I can open a project is to select one of the recents that are displayed. I'm running High Sierra on MacOS and it's up to date. I realize Unity has a newer Personal Version, but this is the version I believe to be compatible for the class. Please help!

Here's what I'm looking at:
When you follow the first link to the picture (I guess I can't embed pics yet), you see where one initiates opening a project in the top right (I added a red arrow). As a note, if I try to go to "File" in the menu and then "Open Scene" or "Open Project" they're greyed out.

If you follow the link to the second picture, selecting the project folder and clicking open doesn't work. Additionally the .sln file, the Program.cs file, and the .csproj file are all greyed out.

[These are pictures of the steps I take](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mls6Y.png)

Comment: Unity does not normally "open" sln files, what exactly are the steps you are doing when you try to open a file. Update your question with the info. Add screenshots if you can.

Comment: Thanks @ScottChamberlain , I've added some screenshots and more detail. Please let me know if you recommend adding anything else.